# Multiple Queue on Homestead is failing and Events don't get fired

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

I currently have a live app that i am making huge changes too so i am working locally using Homestead. I previously used One Queue but with changes and all that i had to run multiple queues. The previous default queues was meant to make rows in a database table and one of the recent ones was to send emails. then i needed another one that I need to make rows in another table as well...issue is sometimes it works and other times it fails and sometimes it only creates one row before failing. the most annoying thing is that it is supposed to fire an event per row created in the database but that does not even occur at all. I had done it effectively before and it never failed me even the default queue still works fine.

here is the controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Redirect;
use App\Short;
use App\Wallet;
use \SplFixedArray;
use App\Jobs\ShortQueuer;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\SlotRequest;

class ShortController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('short_term_goals');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(SlotRequest $request)
    {
        $quota = 2;
        $slotquota = request('slotamount') + $quota;

        if ( auth()->user()->wallet->balance < $slotquota ) {

            return Redirect::back()->with('low_balance', 'You do not have a sufficient wallet balance to reserve these SLOTS. Please Load Up Your Wallet');

        } else {

            // Getting SLOTS as objects of an array
            $slotquantity = new SplFixedArray(request('slotamount'));
            $slotquantity = $slotquantity->toArray();
            $user = auth()->user();

            ShortQueuer::dispatch($slotquantity, $user)->onQueue('shorts');

        }

            //Sorting Wallet Balance
            $wallet = Wallet::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->first();
            $wallet->balance = $wallet->balance - $slotquota;
            $wallet->save();



            //Returning View With Message
            return Redirect::back()->with('reserved', 'Your Short Term Goals are Currently being met .');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Short  $short
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Short $short)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Short  $short
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Short $short)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Short  $short
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Short $short)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Short  $short
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Short $short)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Here is the job

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;


use App\Short;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class ShortQueuer implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $slotquantity;
    protected $user;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(array $slotquantity, $user)
    {
       $this->slotquantity = $slotquantity;
       $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {

       // Inserting Rows in SLOTS Table
       foreach ($this->slotquantity as $short) {

        $short = new Short();

        $short->user_id = $this->user->id;

        $short->save();

         //Slot Counting Event
         event(new ShortCounter);


        }

    }

    public $tries = 1;

    public $timeout = 86400;

    public $retryAfter = 87000;
}
```

here is the event

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class ShortCounter
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```

Here is the listener

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Short;
use App\Goal;
use App\Events\ShortCounter;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class GoalCreator
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  ShortCounter  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(ShortCounter $event)
    {
        $shortcount = Short::all()->count();

        if($shortcount == 800) {

            $goalshort = Short::latest()->first();

            $goal = new Goal();

            $goal->gid = unique_random('goals', 'sgid', 8);

            $goal->grc = unique_random('goals', 'sgrc', 12);

            $goal->status = 0;

            $goal->amount = 200;

            $goal->user_id = $goalshort->user_id;

            $goal->save();

            Short::truncate();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I sort it out.....I went through the error logs and solved the errors one after the other. First I forgot to include the Event Class in the Job, then a column name in my database was wrong then I restarted my server.